# Finding the minimum number of transitions

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

There are a lot of algorithms related to sorting an array of numbers, but I was just wondering if there's an algorithm that calculates a minimum number of transitions to sort the array of numbers.

For instance, if the given array of integers is

```
 a[5]={20, 15, 40, 30, 60}
```

then the minimum number of transitions necessary to sort the array in an ascending order is 2 since all we need to do is switch a[0] with a[1] and a[2] with a[3].

Comment: It may take longer time to find out how many transitions are needed, than actually sort the data. :)

Answer (score 2):

### the minimum number of transitions:

We can use **the inversion number** of a sequence to measure its sortedness.

In your example, `[20, 15, 40, 30, 60]` has two inversion:

`(20, 15), (40, 30)`

> **Note**:
>
> If i < j and A(i) > A(j), then the pair (i, j) is called an inversion of A

So we need to do two transitions.

The inversion number of a sequence is the **minimum number of transitions** to sort the sequence.

### how to get the insersion number:

You can use `standard comparison sorting algorithms`  to compute the inversion number in time `O(n log n)`. The [Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) often used to compute the inversion number.

example code (python2):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8

def merge(a1, n1, a2, n2, a, n):
    c = c1 = c2 =0
    count = 0
    while c < n:
        if c1 == n1:
            while c < n:
                a[c] = a2[c2]
                c = c + 1
                c2 = c2 + 1
        elif c2 == n2:
            while c < n:
                a[c] = a1[c1]
                c = c + 1
                c1 = c1 + 1
        else:
            if a1[c1] > a2[c2]:
                a[c] = a2[c2]
                count = count + n1 - c1
                c = c + 1
                c2 = c2 + 1
            else:
                a[c] = a1[c1]
                c = c + 1
                c1 = c1 + 1
    return count

def Sort(a):
    n = len(a)
    if n == 1: return 0
    n1 = n/2
    n2 = n - n1
    a1 = a[:n1]
    a2 = a[n1:]
    count1 = Sort(a1)
    count2 = Sort(a2)
    c = c1 = c2 = 0
    count = count1 + count2 + merge(a1, n1, a2, n2, a, n)
    return count

array = [8, 2, 3, 1, 6, 5, 9]
print array, 'has %d inversions.' % Sort(array)
array = [20, 15, 40, 30, 60]
print array, 'has %d inversions.' % Sort(array)
```

Actually, the sort process is just remove all inversions. So you can use it to compute the inversion number.

For more infomation you can look the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) :).